# Why lazy loading is reading the data from database earlier than expected?

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I want to know that what exactly lazy loading is? as I know if our entity is mapping with other entities or if contains some entities and we use lazy loading, it fetches data of only that entity and when we require the data of its mapping entities, then it hits the DB for that mapped entity data.

But when I was using it, I fetched the data of an entity, which had some other entities also, when I debug that, it contains the data of that entity and not its mapping entities. Then I changed the data of its mapped entities, manually in DB. Then I get the data of the mapped entities, it returns the earlier data (before changing). This means, lazy loading fetches all the data from the beginning, so what's the benefit of it?

Comment: Your debugger tries to display all the elements of your entity. It does that by iterating over the collections. So it initializes the lazy-loading proxy, which makes you think lazy loading doesn't work. But it does work. Enable SQL logging in Hibernate, and add traces in the code: one before iterating over the collection of associated entities, and one after. See when the SQL query is executed.

Comment: @JBNizet is right. The calls to the getter methods by the debugger will trigger the proxies and will interact with the database at that moment. I suggest you to use `show_sql=true` in your Hibernate configuration to see in logs where the SQL statements are called when using this feature.

Comment: I am agreed with you, but I want to know that when getter called(for mapped entities), it hits the database at that moment (as you said) ,then why it doesn't get the latest value(changed value).